# feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://forex-service/currency-exchange/from/EUR/to/INR\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorExecu

Tags: spring, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I am following microservices code from : http://www.springboottutorial.com/microservices-with-spring-boot-part-5-eureka-naming-server and using latest version of `Spring Boot` and Spring Cloud as of now is `2.1.2.RELEASE` and `Greenwich.RC2`.

When I hit the

> curl -XGET  http://localhost:8100/currency-converter-feign/from/EUR/to/INR/quantity/10000

I am getting below error.

> {"timestamp":"2019-01-21T16:48:19.250+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Read timed out executing GET http://forex-service/currency-exchange/from/EUR/to/INR","trace":"feign.RetryableException: Read timed out executing GET http://forex-service/currency-exchange/from/EUR/to/INR\r\n\tat feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:84)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:113)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78)\r\n\tat feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.retrieveExchangeValue(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.prateek.currencyconversion.CurrencyConversionController.convertCurrencyFeign(CurrencyConversionController.java:47)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\nCaused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out\r\n\tat java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)\r\n\tat java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)\r\n\tat java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)\r\n\tat java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)\r\n\tat java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)\r\n\tat java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)\r\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)\r\n\tat sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)\r\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)\r\n\tat sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)\r\n\tat java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)\r\n\tat feign.Client$Default.convertResponse(Client.java:143)\r\n\tat feign.Client$Default.execute(Client.java:68)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.FeignLoadBalancer.execute(FeignLoadBalancer.java:56)\r\n\tat com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:104)\r\n\tat com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303)\r\n\tat com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287)\r\n\tat rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231)\r\n\tat rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228)\r\n\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeCo100 10754    0 10754    0     0   2397      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--  25201.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:185)\r\n\tat com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)\r\n\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)\r\n\tat rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)\r\n\tat rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)\r\n\tat rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)\r\n\tat rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)\r\n\tat rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)\r\n\tat rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)\r\n\tat rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)\r\n\tat rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)\r\n\tat rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423)\r\n\tat rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390)\r\n\tat rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443)\r\n\tat rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340)\r\n\tat com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:65)\r\n\tat feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:108)\r\n\t... 58 more\r\n","path":"/currency-converter-feign/from/EUR/to/INR/quantity/10000"}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this is working fine now by adding below changes.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

[image]

[image]